# Why is @extend needed now in my code, when the tutorial works without it?

Tags: html, sass

This is a SCSS question.
So I'm following a course where

&__picture = element class="card__picture"

and inside it i have the

&--1 = element class="card__picture--1"

So they guy in the course has properties ONLY inside &__picture that are somehow being passed down to &--1, which is kind of logical to my beginners brain, while for me this does not work unless i put all those properties inside &--1, or use @extend inside &--1 ( something that i found on a quick google and makes my code compute like his ).

My question is, why is there a need for @extend in my code but not in the tutorial code ?

What do I need to learn here ? Did things change meanwhile ?

Here is my code with @extend, the only difference from the original code is that there is no @extend there.

```
&__picture {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 23rem;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 0 100%);

  &--1 {
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, $color-secondary-light, $color-secondary-dark),
        url(../img/nat-5.jpg);
     @extend .card__picture;
  }
```

Comment: I'm sure it isn't the cause of the issue you have described but you are missing a closing bracket in your code `&--1` should be nested inside of `&__picture`

Comment: @AaronMcGuire oh yea sorry, for sure is in my code, thanks https://imgur.com/a/Ft3Mlc8

Comment: Are you sure that the html isn't `<div class="card__picture card__picture--1">` ? That's how you use a modifier in BEM methodology.

Comment: @AmauryHanser that was it! my BEM was wrong! how do i mark your solution as solved ?

Comment: No need, you're welcome ;)